# Pyramid. Can't debug or run server from Eclipse directly

Tags: python, pyramid

I can't get Eclipse to debug Pyramid and searching there doesn't seem to be an easy way, however I assumed I could use the basic built in server for this purpose (after creating my scaffold):

```
app=config.make_wsgi_app()
server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)
server.serve_forever()
```

But when I navigate to my url (debugging takes me to the serve_forever and) I can see this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2015 16:36:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 153
```

But no more code is being called?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I RTFM and it worked and I'm up and running in Eclipse ;)

http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging/pydev.html